# How do i add grid and list in same layout (RecyclerView or something similar) in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to add grid and list in same layout (RecyclerView or something similar) in android.
where grid can be multiple products and a list to label the products. 2 products in the grid width.
this is the one i did in RecyclerView for items only IMAGE->:
[only products no title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHbSM.png)

Now i want to label the items below it

I want it to be like this, possibly in an efficient way IMAGE->:
[Multiple items under 1 label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZyyW.png)

tried adding label and items in same RecycleView, Label also added as a product item

public class CustomCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<Object> itemsData;
private Context mContext;
private final int title = 0;
private final int productItem = 1;


public CustomCategoryAdapter(Activity context, List<Object> itemsData) {
    mContext = context;
    this.itemsData = itemsData;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemsData.size();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v1;
    switch(viewType)
    {
        case title:
            v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.title_layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new TitleLayout(v1);
            return viewHolder;
        case productItem:
            v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ProductListingRecyclerGridAdapter.ViewHolder(v1);
            return viewHolder;
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    try {
        switch(viewHolder.getItemViewType())
        {
            case title:
                TitleLayout titleLayout = (TitleLayout) viewHolder;
                titleLayout.setTitle((String)itemsData.get(position));
                break;
            case productItem:
                ProductListingRecyclerGridAdapter.ViewHolder productDetail = (ProductListingRecyclerGridAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder;
                productDetail.itemprice.setText(((ProductItem)itemsData.get(position)).getProductPrice());
                productDetail.txtViewTitle.setText(((ProductItem)itemsData.get(position)).getTitle());
                //productDetail.imgViewIcon.setImageUrl(((ProductItem)itemsData.get(position)).getImageUrl(),GORSingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader());
                break;
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (itemsData.get(position) instanceof String) {
        return title;
    } else if (itemsData.get(position) instanceof ProductItem) {
        return productItem;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

}

Comment: Post your code for your adapter and we can likely help modify it to do what you need it to. You can have different view types managed by different holders within the same adapter.

Comment: i posted it check it out!

Comment: You could modify things so that each row of the list contains a grid-like layout with 2 possible items. If there is only 1 item to show just don't fill the second view in the row with anything.